# problem with PHP class function ()

Tags: php, class

this is my first question here and i hope you can help me ..

I am trying to find a soloution of the towers of hanoi problem by three search ways (BFS-DFS-IDS) so I use "state" class whitch defined by 5 variables as here :

> class state {
>
> ```
> var $tower1 = array();
> var $tower2 = array();
> var $tower3 = array();
> var $depth;
> var $neighbors = array();
> ```

and it also has many function one of them is getneighbors() which supposed to fill the array  $neighbors  with state neighbors and they are from the type "state"

and here is the function :

function getneighbors ()

```
{

    $temp=$this->copy();

    $neighbor1= $this->copy();

    $neighbor2= $this->copy();

    $neighbor3= $this->copy();

    $neighbor4= $this->copy();

    $neighbor5= $this->copy();

    $neighbor6= $this->copy();

    if(!Empty($temp->tower1))
    {

         if(!Empty($neighbor1->tower2))
         {
            if(end($neighbor1->tower1) < end($neighbor1->tower2))
            {
                array_unshift($neighbor1->tower2,array_pop($neighbor1->tower1));
                array_push($neighbors,$neighbor1);
         }}
         else
             {
         array_unshift($neighbor1->tower2, array_pop($neighbor1->tower1));             
          array_push($neighbors,$neighbor1);
             }



        if(!Empty($neighbor2->tower3))
         {
            if(end($neighbor2->tower1) < end($neighbor2->tower3))
            { array_unshift($neighbor2->tower3, array_pop($neighbor2->tower1));
              array_push($neighbors,$neighbor2);
        }}


        else
            {
         array_unshift($neighbor2->tower3,array_shift($neighbor2->tower1));
         array_push($neighbors,$neighbor2);
            }

        }
               if(!Empty($temp->tower2))
    {


         if(!Empty($neighbor3->tower1))
         {

           if(end($neighbor3->tower2) < end($neighbor3->tower1))
           {   array_unshift($neighbor3->tower1,array_shift($neighbor3->tower2));
               array_push($neighbors,$neighbor3);
         }

         }
             else
             {
         array_unshift($neighbor3->tower1,array_shift($neighbor3->tower2));
         array_push($neighbors,$neighbor3);

         }



        if(!Empty($neighbor4->tower3))
         {
            if(end($neighbor4->tower2) < end($neighbor4->tower3))
            { array_unshift($neighbor4->tower1,array_shift($neighbor4->tower2));
              array_push($neighbors,$neighbor4);
            }
        }
            else{
         array_unshift($neighbor4->tower3,array_shift($neighbor4->tower2));
            array_push($neighbors,$neighbor4);
         }

        }
          if(!Empty($temp->tower3))
    {


         if(!Empty($neighbor5->tower1))
         {
            if(end($neighbor5->tower3) < end($neighbor5->tower1))
            {array_unshift($neighbor5->tower1,array_shift($neighbor5->tower3));
             array_push($neighbors,$neighbor5);
            }
         }
             else{
         array_unshift($neighbor5->tower1,array_shift($neighbor5->tower3));
         array_push($neighbors,$neighbor5);}



        if(!Empty($neighbor6->tower2))
         {
            if(end($neighbor6->tower3) < end($neighbor6->tower2))
            {  array_unshift($neighbor6->tower2,array_shift($neighbor6->tower3));
             array_push($neighbors,$neighbor6);
        }}
            else{
         array_unshift($neighbor6->tower2,array_shift($neighbor6->tower3));
         array_push($neighbors,$neighbor6);}

        }
        return $neighbors;
}
```

note that toString and equals and copy  are defined too

now the problem is that when I call getneighbors() it returns an empty $neighbors array

can you pleas tell me the problem ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the larger declaration. `getneighbors()` is in a class I take it? What class? WHere are the above 5 variables defined? Are they class variables or globals? Edit: i see the class {} above, missed it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a scoping issue. `$neighbors` is a class variable and not a PHP global. Everywhere you refer to `$neighbors` change it to `$this->neighbors`.

Comment: thank you 

but the output still the same : (

any body can help ?

Comment: Can you update the class in your posting so we can see the updated code? Please post the class verbatim. I'm not sure if it's 'allowed' with SO but maybe using a pastie service (pastie.org) would be better?